# How to get Location Permission screen at once

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions, android-settings

I want to go Location Permission screen in my Application.

How to get Location Permission screen at once.

Thanks.

I don't want ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS / ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS.

Perhaps the screen I want is the one that can be accessed by pressing at ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS screen it once more.

Comment: And if you request permission for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION?